# Google Analytics report to multiple profiles at the same time on different domains

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have two different GA profiles that I want to report to all the time. This HTML that will have the tracking code will also be run from different top-level domains.

Reading these links:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#MultipleCommands
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

I created this sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
        var subdomain = parts.shift();
        var topleveldomain = parts.join('.');

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(
                ['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-5'],
                ['_setDomainName', topleveldomain],
                ['_setAllowLinker', true]
                ['_trackPageview'],
                ['b._setAccount', 'UA-12345-2'],
                ['b._setDomainName', topleveldomain],
                ['b._setAllowLinker', true]
                ['b._trackPageview']
                );

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script');
            ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/testing-ga/']);">Play</a>
</body>
```

I used JavaScript to determine the top-level domain of the site hosting the tracking code, so it sets the command of _setDomainName to the value of the current domain.

I also added a link with a onclick event to send _trackPageview to GA for testing purposes.

The problem I'm having is that when the page loads, it doesn't sends the request to GA (should send page views request to a different profile each). This is not happening.

It just sends the request to one profile (the first in the array) when I do the onclick event, the normal page view is not firing up.

However, it does sends the page view requests if I remove the: ['_setAllowLinker', true] from both items of the array. But I need that if I'm going to be hosting the tracking code under different top-level domains, right?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple of commas in your `_gaq.push()` parameters:

```
        _gaq.push(
            ['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-5'],
            ['_setDomainName', topleveldomain],
            ['_setAllowLinker', true],           <===
            ['_trackPageview'],
            ['b._setAccount', 'UA-12345-2'],
            ['b._setDomainName', topleveldomain],
            ['b._setAllowLinker', true],         <===
            ['b._trackPageview']
            );
```

Comment: http://www.beeskneesdance.com/bees_knees/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/homer-simpson-doh.gif

D'oh, I feel like Homer Simpson. That's the effects of working on a Sunday with a hangover. haha, Thanks.